# Python - Build a tuple list according to the character frequencies in the input

Tags: python, list, count, tuples

I have a function `buildFrequencyList` that should work like this:

```
>>> L = []
>>> buildFrequencyList(L, 'bbaabtttaabtctce')
>>> L
[(4, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 't'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'e')]
```

Here is the code:

```
def buildFrequencyList(outputList, dataIN):
    for c in dataIN:
        a = 1
        bo = True
        if outputList == []:
            outputList.append((a,c))
        for i in outputList:
            (a,b) = i 
            if b==c:
                bo= False
                a +=1 
        if(bo):
            outputList.append((1,c))    
    return outputList
```

But the output actually is:

```
[(1, 'b'), (1, 'a'), (1, 't'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'e')]
```

I don't know why. Can somebody explain to me what the problem is?

**Edit**:

I modified the code and I have really strange output:

```
def buildFrequencyList(outputList, dataIN):
    for c in range(len(dataIN)):
        if outputList == []:
            outputList.append((1,dataIN[c]))
        for i in range(len(outputList)): 
            (a,b) = outputList[i]
            if b==dataIN[c]:
                outputList[i] = (a+1,b)
            else:        
                outputList.append((1,dataIN[c]))    
    return outputList
```

the output:

```
[(5, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (5, 't'), (5, 't'), (5, 't'), (5, 't'), (5, 't'), (4, 't')...] # is infinite
```

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: [(4, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 't'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'e')]

Comment: But you never actually update the values in the list. Tuples and integers are *immutable*.

Comment: Any reason for not using `collections.Counter`?

Comment: the objective is to code without count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your code:

```
def buildFrequencyList(outputList, dataIN):
    for c in dataIN:
        a = 1
        bo = True
        if outputList == []:
            outputList.append((a,c))
        for i in outputList:
            (a,b) = i 
            if b==c:
                bo= False
                a +=1 
        if(bo):
            outputList.append((1,c))    
    return outputList
```

Now let's consider some cases. First, the case where the `outputList` is empty:

```
a = 1
bo = True
if outputList == []:
    outputList.append((a,c))
```

Now, notice that there is never a value in `a` other than 1. This is one of those cases where it's okay to use a "magic number", because it should be obvious that you're counting things (based on the function name, since you provide no docs).

```
if outputList == []:
   outputList.append((1,c))
```

But wait! Because the for loop will execute zero times on an empty list. So the code at the bottom:

```
if (bo):
    outputList.append((1,c))
```

would do the same job as this code. This code is totally unnecessary. Just delete it.

Now, what if the outputList is *not* empty?

```
for i in outputList:
    (a,b) = i
    if b == c:
        bo = False
        a += 1
```

What does this do? It increments `a`, which is fine - the count is one higher. It sets `bo` to `False`, to indicate something. I guess maybe that you found an entry in the list so a new object is not needed.

Then what happens to `a`?

```
    if (bo):
        outputList.append((1,c))
return outputList
```

NOTHING! You never use `a` again.

So there's your problem: the times when you already have an entry in the list, you never update it.

**How can you fix it?**

The short answer is that you can't. Because *tuples are immutable.* This means you can't mutate (or 'change') the values stored in a tuple. You have to throw the tuple away, and build a new one with the correct values in it.

One solution might be to `.remove()` the tuple from the list, and then append a new tuple `(a,c)` after incrementing `a`.

```
for tpl in outputList:
    freq,val = tpl
    if val == c:
        outputList.remove(tpl)   # INVALIDATES FOR LOOP! MUST BREAK!
        outputList.append((freq+1,val))
        bo = False
        break
```

Another solution might be to use `enumerate(outputList)` to get an index and a value, then overwrite the tuple like this:

```
for i, freq in outputList:
    if freq[1] == c:
        outputList[i] = (freq[0]+1, freq[1])
        break
```

Another choice would be to hold the frequency info in a separate container, like a dictionary, until you have a "final" count, then go through and append all the counts to the list at one time.

```
counts = collections.defaultdict(0)
for c in dataIN:
    counts[c] += 1
for char,count in counts.items():
    outputList.append((count,char))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating your list, and instead your local variables. You are also doing a lot of unnecessary computations. (See @jonrsharpe's comment)

A clearer way to achieve the desired output would be:

```
def build_frequency_list(s):
    return [(s.count(c), c) for c in sorted(set(s))]
```

Result:

```
>>> [(s.count(c), c) for c in sorted(set(s))]
[(4, 'a'), (4, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'e'), (5, 't')]
```

Comment: I can't use the count function. I want to create my own code

Comment: Why can't you use it? There is a reason such methods are present in the standard library.

Comment: Because I'm a student and the objective is to code this function without count

Comment: @J.caste isn't the objective for *you* to figure out how to code it?

Comment: Yes but i'm block on this function and i need it to continue my exercice

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = 'bbaabtttaabtctce'
d = defaultdict(int)
for c in s:
    d[c] += 1
d.items()
```

The obvious answer is

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(s).items()
```

but you said you cannot use it.

Comment: I can't use dictionnary